Can I summarize and paraphrase someone's findings and cite their authors and make it for my references?
I was using other researchers' sources. I want to summarize, paraphrase, and cite the authors of that previous study. I was writing my research paper and I stumbled upon important information, but the problem is I summarized and paraphrased it and cited the authors. Is this considered plagiarism?

Welcome to Writing.SE! Please try and make sure that your spelling, grammar, and punctuation are as good as possible, to help reduce the chance that we won't understand what you're asking.

If I understand the question correctly, you found a source that cited another source and only cited that other source. The correct way to cite that depends on the citation style you are using, but generally, it is something like

(Emerson, 1970, as cited in Lake and Palmer, 1977, p. 30).

I don't think it would be plagiarism to cite only Emerson here, but it is not good practice. After all, Lake and Palmer may not have summarised Emerson's research correctly.
An alternative would be to go and find the original source and paraphrase/summarise that.

If you indicate your source, it is not plagiarism. You can cite your sources word by word:

Williams (1956) wrote: "The sun rises in the east."

Or you can paraphrase what your source says:

Williams (1956) writes that the sun rises in the east.

Both is possible and acceptable.
